# The role of semi-colons in defining local file variables

Tags: variables, emacs

I am learning about lexical and dynamic scoping (and consequently file variables).

Many resources recommend updating the `lexical-binding` file variable using

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

or

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

However, in the [Specifying Local File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) documentation, the general assignment form is

```
-*- mode: modename; var: value; … -*-
```

Following that form, I would expect the a `lexical-binding` definition to look like

```
-*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

So, I've tested it.  I have a file named `lexical-scratch.el`.  The first line is one of the file variable specifications (either with or without semi-colons).  I save the buffer and then call `M-x revert-buffer`.  When I do that, calling `C-h v lexical-binding` shows that the variable has been updated.  I can repeat this procedure using `nil` in place of `t` to reset the variable.

Running all forms appear to have the same effect of updating the file variable.

Why do the leading semi-colons not comment out the assignment?  Is it because semi-colons are treated as delimiters between file variables?  If so, how does Emacs differentiate between semi-colons marking comments and delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File local variable specifications are not elisp, and can be part of any file type (C program, text file, etc.).

Therefore, they can be protected by the mode's comment delimiters in order to not interfere with, for example, a compiler reading this same file.

In this case, the semicolons are there as elisp comments, so you can eval the buffer with no error. The number of semicolons [is a commenting convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comment-Tips.html#Comment-Tips) only.

Comment: Does the file local variable come from the parts of Emacs which are implemented in C, then?

Comment: Not necessarily. The same file that you edit with emacs will probably be read by some other software (HTML parser, Python interpreter, C compiler, whatever), so you must be able to comment the file local variable token in order not to break the file semantics. Try to `eval-buffer` without the semicolons and it will fail.

Comment: I don't understand your comment Lorem Ipsum, but I think maybe you were confused by the mention of "C program" in the answer. Because the `-*-` line is part of the file, it will therefore be seen by *whatever* software may need to parse the file, but it will not be *valid syntax* for any such parser, so it needs to be a comment. The comment syntax is dependent on the kind of file. e.g. `// -*- indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-` might be used in a Javascript program.

Comment: Emacs essentially searches for that `-*-` on the first line of the file (ignoring whatever characters preceded it, because it doesn't care what kind of file or comment syntax was needed), and starts processing the variables from there. See the code for `hack-local-variables-prop-line` if you want the precise details.